# How can I increased my site traffic

Tags: web-crawlers, sitemap, traffic, web-traffic

My website releated to entertainment and movies trailer and review based site, my site viewers list actually very low, I have set keywords which is found from google keywords planner. And created sitemap. Right after my site improvements not good, may I need any changes according to my site traffic and viewers increments.

Answer (score 0):

Hard niche to compete in. You got really big boys owning that market.

To start, get backlinks and make sure you have unique content. Creating a blog is a nice way of getting that unique content.